# How do I check all voice channels to see if anyone is in them?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a bot that can check all voice channels to see if anyone is in them and join the one with the most people in and then play sounds.
I have attached my code below.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.player import FFmpegPCMAudio
from discord.utils import get
import datetime

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="<")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready")
MINUTE = 0

@bot.command()
async def start(ctx):
    while not bot.is_closed():
        while not "00" in str(MINUTE):
            MINUTE = datetime.datetime.now().minute
            if "00" in str(MINUTE):
                hour = datetime.datetime.now().hour
                number = hour
                while number > 0:
                    # here is where I need the code to check all voice channels and find the one with the most people in
                    voice = await channel.connect()
                    source = FFmpegPCMAudio('audio source')
                    player = voice.play(source)
                    number = number-1



bot.run("my bot token")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through all [voice channel](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.VoiceChannel) members to find the channel with the most.